# Keeping variables during recursion (return the initial value after recursion)

Tags: variables, recursion, common-lisp

How do I keep a variable in a recursive function?
Let's say I have this function and want to print the initial value i put in, if so this code does not do the job, it will only return 5. How can I man this work? It's something with gensym I presume.

```
(defun cprog (x) 
  (let ((d x)) 
    (if (< x 5) 
      (cprog (1+ x)) 
      (print d))))
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "not do the job"? What is the job it's supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe use `(progn (print d) x)`

Comment: What's the reason for the `d` variable? You don't need it, you can just use `(print x)`.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. What i mean is that (cprog 1) should return 1 and not 5, I don't want the d variable to be overwritten every recursion.

Comment: This is unrelated but your program is basically `(lambda (x) (print (max 5 x)) x)`

Comment: Can you give us examples of expected output for some example inputs? Because I have the suspicion that there are more than one mistake in your code.

Answer (score 3):

After making the recursive call, return the current parameter.

```
(defun cprog (x) 
  (if (< x 5) 
    (cprog (1+ x))
    (print x))
  x)
```

`(cprog 1)` will print `5` at the end of the recursion and return `1`.

Answer (score 3):

[Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76104782/3673) is OK for your simple case, but mind the consequences of such implementation: **it cannot do tail-recursion** as each call to `cprog` must be stored on the program call stack because after each `cprog` call, `x` must be returned.
Not having tail-recursion is not a problem for your simple case, but in a production environment you'd rather implement it like that :

```
(defun cprog (x &optional (res x))
  (if (< x 5)
      (cprog (1+ x) res)
      (and (print x) res)))
```

In this implementation, you use tail-recursion, that is : your common lisp compiler transforms your recursion into a simple loop (It can be seen by consulting dissambly of those functions), and thus your program call stack is not exhausted by too many function calls due to recursion.

In a production system, this is important as you may have a lot of recursion and if you're not using tail-recursion, you may have a "Program stack overflow".